# random ssl errors loading assets

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, ssl-certificate, shopify, cdn

I'm doing apps for Shopify, one of my apps show random ssl errors when trying to load jquery or bootstrap and even font awesome, i'm loading all of those from their cdn, so i assume they don't have any errors there.

This is how i load them:

```
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!---INCLUDE jquery ui from google -->

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This is just copy paste from the instructions each of them gave (css files loaded same).

**Now, the funny thing that i'm getting errors randomly, sometimes i don't get any errors**, sometimes its just font awesome css having error loading, sometimes its both of the jquery and the jquery-ui code (always both, never only one of them), for example:

```
GET https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js net::ERR_SSL_DECRYPT_ERROR_ALERT
GET https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js net::ERR_SSL_DECRYPT_ERROR_ALERT
```

and after refresh (ctrl + f5):

```
GET https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
GET https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
GET https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
GET https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
GET https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
GET https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

And this behavior keeps going, sometimes only bootstrap don't load, sometimes everything is loaded.

Those errors happen all the time on one of my apps, but i did had those errors on other app as well (for couple of times and then it was gone, i did nothing to fix it).

Also as you can see from the errors above there are 2 type of errors, those errors show up when i do a simple refresh (didn't do anything differently)

**What makes me crazy is the fact that it looks random and this only happens on chrome, everything works with firefox**, my app is loaded in an iframe inside shopify website, so if my server had any ssl issues, it wouldn't load at all.

I've tried everything, i'm trying for the past 3 days, i don't remember when everything started, but 3 days i'm trying to do different stuff to fix it with no luck.

I've tried:

1.reinstall chrome

2.disable quic on chrome

3.remove every extension (errors on incognito as well)

4.clear the ssl list in chrome

5.disable ssl checking in my eset (disabled every web checking for eset)

6.made sure my server have working ssl (example: https://sellerpanda.com/mass-edit)

basically i read every guide about those errors and followed it, nothing helped.

I'm using windows and ubuntu in a virtual machine, same errors happen only on chrome on both of the OS.

How do i fix it? if something were wrong with the ssl on my server, i would get those errors all the time and not in a random way, also my app wouldn't load in shopify's iframe.

But i did reinstalled chrome on both OS and it didn't work (also deleted files)

***UPDATE 1***

I created a new user profile to test if this was the issue (m,aybe forgot to delete some files when i uninstalled chrome), for the first look of it it was working for the first 100 refreshes (yes 100!!!) but this is not the fix because it still came back after a while, it actually made it appear less, but this is still random, and still is a problem, i have tested this issue on my laptop, this happens there as well (ubuntu chrome only)

So the last thing i can think about is or the cdn have some kind of problem (unlikely that 2 cdn's have the same problem only with my website)

Or my internet provider have something to do with it, i will call them soon to figure this out.

Comment: Do you have any progress on this? One of my client has the same weirdness... ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR for https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js

Comment: I actually didn't fix it, but shopify did, i don't know what exactly was the issue, one day it stopped making those errors, so i assume shopify had to do something with that issue got fixed.